# I can't connect to my postgresql database

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on wsl and installed postgres true the normal `sudo apt-get install`.
I know that there are related questions but none have solved my problem.

Whenever I run psql  it returns me this error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried to restart/start the psql server but then this error occured

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 13 database server                                                                                                            * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1:
2021-06-15 22:40:51.285 CEST [74] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2021-06-15 22:40:51.297 CEST [74] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-06-15 22:40:51.297 CEST [74] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2021-06-15 22:40:51.297 CEST [74] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-06-15 22:40:51.297 CEST [74] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-06-15 22:40:51.304 CEST [74] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Comment: did you checked that the service is running : `sudo service postgresql status` if it's not active then start it `sudo service postgresql start`

Comment: Looks like the server is already running. The Debian/Ubuntu binaries create a data directory and start the server (with default settings) when you install the server package. Very annoying.

Comment: What happens if you do `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -d <db_name> ...`